# appropriate authentication method for sharepoint hosted custom app in sharepoint 2013

Tags: 2013, authentication, sharepoint-hosted-app

I want to develop a sharepoint hosted application which will have some custom functionality ,

from below options which one i should select  for appropriate authentication method for this app

1. sharepoint  Server to Server Security token service (STS)
2. Use the Open Authorization 2.0 ( OAuth 2.0 ) web authorization  protocol